# How to combine display, opacity and transition?

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following.

CSS:

```
.action .menu {
   opacity: 0;
   align-items: center;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   min-width: 200px;
   background: var(--background-color);
   transform: translateY(-43px);
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-43px);
   -moz-transform: translateY(-43px);
   -ms-transform: translateY(-43px);
   -o-transform: translateY(-43px);
   border-radius: 30px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
   -moz-border-radius: 30px;
   -ms-border-radius: 30px;
   -o-border-radius: 30px;
   transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
   display: none;
}

.action .menu.active{
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 14px;
    transform: translateY(-44px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-44px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-44px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-44px);
    -o-transform: translateY(-44px);
    display: block; 
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function ToggleMenu() {
    const togglemenu = document.querySelector('.menu');

    togglemenu.classList.toggle('active')
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="action">
  <div class="profile border_account mt-2 col-6  ms-2  " onclick="ToggleMenu()">

    <div class=" display_account" >

          <img class="rounded-2 image_acc my-1 mx-2 me-1" src="pictures/black.png" alt="">

          <p class="truncate my-1 mx-2 font_bold pt-0 pb-2">eskandari.bemolaaaaaaaaaa</p>

          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30px" height="30px" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-caret-down-fill " viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M7.247 11.14 2.451 5.658C1.885 5.013 2.345 4 3.204 4h9.592a1 1 0 0 1 .753 1.659l-4.796 5.48a1 1 0 0 1-1.506 0z"/>
          </svg>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="menu me-2">
      <ul class=" p-0 m-0">
        <li class=" account_container display_account2 pb-1 ms-2 mb-3 rounded-3" onclick="ToggleMenu()">              
  
                <img class="rounded-2 image_acc2 my-1 mx-2" src="pictures/black.png" alt="">

                <p class="truncate2 my-1 mx-2 font_bold pt-0 pb-2">eskandar.eskandary.eskandarpoor</p>

                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30px" height="30px" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-caret-up-fill " viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                  <path d="m7.247 4.86-4.796 5.481c-.566.647-.106 1.659.753 1.659h9.592a1 1 0 0 0 .753-1.659l-4.796-5.48a1 1 0 0 0-1.506 0z"/>
                </svg>

        </li>
        <div class="line mx-auto"></div>
          <li class="li_account pb-1 my-1 mx-2"><a href="#" class="font_regular text-center my-1 width_100">پروفایل من</a></li>
          <div class="line mx-auto"></div>
          <li class="li_account pb-1 my-1 mx-2 "><a href="#" class="font_regular my-1 text-center logout_ width_100">خروج</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

which its displayed by clicking the button (onclick adds the class action).

It's working pretty nice expect I can't make the display none to display block with animation.

I've tried to add transition to opacity.

The problem with opacity itself without any display none to block is that elements down this absolut div are not clickable so I must add display to this.

Can someone give it an animation so it doesn't pop up?

Comment: Please add also your relevant html and js code

Comment: Transitions do not work with the display property. You only need display none if your looking to remove the object from the DOM order. If you just want to hide it use overflow hidden then transition opacity and height. Opacity removes the items before they are squished by the height transition. I think you can use height 0 and height unset. You'll need to add a delay to display block being applied if you do need to change the DOM order